# In intelliJ 13 ultimate, how do you increase the compiler maximum heap size?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 13 from 11.  There used to be a box under setting/java compiler where you could over ride the compiler maximum heap size.  It is no longer there.  This is stopping me from compiling my project do to a "GC overhead limit exceeded."  Can someone tell me where this option is or a viable alternative?  Any and all information would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Care to give os you running on ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer wouldn't make a difference

Comment: @Justin see answer, or use the 64bit version

Comment: Find idea.vmoptions in the install directory and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> Setting -> Compiler

**Build process heap size (MBytes)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

alter the vm options file in the intellij install directory.

Alternatively fix the problem that causes out of memory errors.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that just changes the options used by the JVM instance that IntelliJ itself runs on, and not the memory used for the build command(s).